# C# Unity Dependency Injection, how can I retrieve an enumerable of instances?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm trying to register multiple instances of the same class so that when I inject an enumerable of that class, I retrieve all instances.

```
public class ActionDialogType
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}



public class ActionDialogTypeUser
{
    private IEnumerable<ActionDialogType> _types;
    public ActionDialogTypeUser(IEnumerable<ActionDialogType> types)
    {
        _types = types
    }
    public void DoSomethingWithTypes()
    {
        // Do Something with types
    }
}
```

So far i've got:

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    public IUnityContainer Register()
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        ActionDialogType actionDialogType1 = new ActionDialogType
        {
            Name = "Something",
            Type = typeof(Something)
        };
        container.RegisterInstance<IActionDialogType>(actionDialogType1, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        ActionDialogType actionDialogType2 = new ActionDialogType
        {
            Name = "SomethingElse",
            Type = typeof(SomethingElse)
        };
        container.RegisterInstance<ActionDialogType>(actionDialogType2, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<ActionDialogType>, ActionDialogType[]>();

        return container;
    }
}
```

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Seems like an odd thing to do, but wouldn't you just add those `ActionDialogType`s to an array and `RegisterInstance` of that array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just register dependencies **with names** then resolve:

```
...
 container.RegisterInstance<IActionDialogType>("actionDialogType1", actionDialogType1, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
...
 container.RegisterInstance<IActionDialogType>("actionDialogType2", actionDialogType2, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

 var actionDialogTypeUser = container.Resolve<ActionDialogTypeUser>();
```

Also constructor should have same types (interfaces in your case):

```
public ActionDialogTypeUser(IEnumerable<IActionDialogType> types)
{
    _types = types
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve an `IEnumerable` of the dependencies with:

```
container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IActionDialogType>, IActionDialogType[]>();
```

Since Unity understands an array, you simply would map the enumerable to an array of the same type.  Which would allow you to return an enumerable of the instance.

Then you could simply do the following:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
     private readonly IEnumerable<IActionDialogType> actionDialogType;
     public ExampleController(IActionDialogType actionDialogType)
     {
         this.actionDialogType = actionDialogType;
     }

     public IActionResult Get()
     {
         foreach(IActionDialogType instance in actionDialogType)
         {
              // Should expose via each now.
              var name = instance.GetType().Name;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to resolve instances of a class though.  Your answer only deals with Resolving types

Comment: @chris31389 I made a change, if this was asp.net core it would be as simple as `Container.GetAllInstances<T>();`